# Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am new to Protractor (can say just 1 day old) and have been trying to run end to end test.

However, every time I run conf.js, I am being displayed with "Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds."

Before posting this question, have tried all options given by other respondents, but still am unable to resolve the issue and thus request your help.

To support, below are the details of my configurations and spec js files:

Conf.js:

```
    exports.config = {
      directConnect: true,
      capabilities: {'browserName': 'chrome'},
      framework: 'jasmine',
      specs: ['example_spec.js'],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000
      }
     };
```

example_spec.js:

```
    describe('forfirm homepage', function() {
        it('login window should open', function() {
         browser.get('https://www.forfirm.com');
         element(by.model('forfirm.email')).sendKeys('email@email.com');
         element(by.model('form.password')).sendKeys('Password');
             });
         });
```

Output received:

```
      Failures:
       1) forfirm homepage login window should open
       Message:
         Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md. The following tasks were pending:
       - $timeout: function (){a.next(),h=f(j,5e3)}
       Stack:
       Error: Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md. The following tasks were pending:
        - $timeout: function (){a.next(),h=f(j,5e3)}
    at /Users/rohitgathibandhe/npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:101:16
    at Promise.invokeCallback_ (/Users/rohitgathibandhe/npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1329:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/rohitgathibandhe/npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2790:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/rohitgathibandhe/npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2773:21)

   1 spec, 1 failure
   Finished in 22.022 seconds
   [launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
   [launcher] chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
    [launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
    [launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

Also, while running the protractor conf.js, I could not see protractor launching Chrome browser.

Comment: `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` in onPrepare solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look on [Timeouts](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md) and try to set all of them first

```
allScriptsTimeout: 120000,
getPageTimeout: 120000,
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000
},
```

Update:
i hate ignoreSynchronization, you should read about it, how to avoid it in official protractor documentation - try this:

conf.js

```
exports.config = {
directConnect: true,
capabilities: {'browserName': 'chrome'},
framework: 'jasmine',
specs: ['example_spec.js'],
allScriptsTimeout: 120000,
getPageTimeout: 120000,
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000
},
onPrepare: function () {
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
}};
```

example_spec.js

```
describe('forfirm homepage', function() {
it('login window should open', function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get('https://www.forfirm.com');
    element(by.model('form.email')).sendKeys('email@email.com');
    element(by.model('form.password')).sendKeys('Password');
    browser.sleep(5000);
});});
```

Comment: I added above suggestions but getting error as, ERROR - failed loading configuration file conf.js
/Users/rohitgathibandhe/npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/FFAutomation/conf.js:17
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)

Comment: And if I comment "defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000", I get an error "A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow." Failures:
1) Forfirm Login Login functionality
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 30.108 seconds

Comment: I have tried everything but nothing is working. Considering the error message I added "allScriptsTimeout: timeout_in_millis" to my cons.js file as suggested on https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md but its giving me error ERROR - failed loading configuration file conf.js , please suggest some solution

Comment: The Error you receive is for a bad syntax. Maybe Angular has never done in your app and polling requests or something. I update my answer

Answer (score 3):

I believe this should solve the issue, as per Protractor official documentation at "https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md".

Interestingly, in our application, I see that this still takes 11 seconds default even though I have set the allScriptsTimeout to a value say 120 seconds.

I tried doing this in OnPrepare too, despite that I am seeing the same time out error stating Protractor synching with the page for 11 seconds. Any thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Below is an example of my config (Node - 4.2.4, Protractor - 3.1.1)

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['DemoTest.js'],
  getPageTimeout: 120000,
  allScriptsTimeout: 120000,

  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    },

  onPrepare: function(){
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
      getPageTimeout: 120000;
      allScriptsTimeout: 120000;
      jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 180000;

   },
}
```